# VsCode debugging with c++17 fails?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code, gdb

I'm getting an issue where I can build and run a project with c++17 flags enabled, but I can't actually debug it. The debugger launches in vsCode, but all the c++ 17 features are red squiggled, and those lines never execute properly. I'm guessing it's a problem with my launch.json, but I can't figure out what it is that I'm missing...

I'm running windows 10, and here's the relevant configuration in vsCode:

tasks.json:

```
{
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
        "command": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
        "args": [
            "-std=c++17",
            "-g",
            "${fileDirname}\\*.cpp",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "Generated task by Debugger"
    }
],
"version": "2.0.0"
```

}

launch.json:

```
    {
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++.exe - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": ["-std=c++17"],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welp - not much of an answer, but the issue isn't happening when I just use cl.exe as the compiler instead of gcc. I've since just stopped using gcc for this project after trying to get it to work for about an hour.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc